Problem updating colors on my website in php
I change the color in my .CSS but when I go to my site the colors remain the old ones.
Did you know why the colors don't update?
I have already tried to change the name, replacing ".current" with something else, I tried to delete and put back the ccs, nothing works.

Have you tried to remove the cache of your browser: disable cache in network when you inspect the code

Thank you, problem solved thanks to you, I didn't think to clear the cache.

This sounds almost like a cache issue. Try to open the webpage in another browser or to refresh the page with ctrl + F5. If this doesn't work I would think you edited the wrong item.
